# Why it's giving error at line number 14?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$rank=1;
$name="Saumik";
$tot_money=55555555.55;
$my_oct=0167;
$my_hex=0xabe;
print "Name: $name\n";
print "Rank $rank\n";
print "Total Prize Money: $tot_money\n";
print "My Octal Number: $my_oct\n";
print "My Hexadecimal Number: $my_hex\n":
```

> syntax error at salar.pl line 14, near ""My Hexadecimal Number: $my_hex\n":" Execution of salar.pl aborted due to compilation errors. Press any key to continue

Comment: Why are you asking about line 14 of an 11 line program? What error is it giving? Why are you not using `use strict;` and `use warnings;`? Why aren't you following the instructions Stackoverflow provides for formatting code?

Comment: syntax error at salar.pl line 14, near ""My Hexadecimal Number: $my_hex\n":"
Execution of salar.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: And what is the last character on that line?

Answer (score 4):

```
print "My Hexadecimal Number: $my_hex\n":
                                     ---^
```

Syntax error - it should be a semicolon.

Also: Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` You can also format your code on Stack Overflow by selecting it and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> (whilst in edit mode). However if you are getting an error - it's useful to include that in your post.